# Civibuild Install - Unable to connect to github.com

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

I got the following error while running `civibuild install` after few stuff got installed.

```
.
.
.
bower resolved      https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.3
bower resolved      https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.3
bower progress      jquery-ui#>=1.9 Receiving objects:  61% (427/700), 508.00 KiB | 45.00 KiB/s
bower progress      font-awesome#~4.4 Receiving objects:  76% (869/1141), 1.46 MiB | 25.00 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery-ui#>=1.9 Receiving objects:  66% (462/700), 596.00 KiB | 53.00 KiB/s
bower progress      font-awesome#~4.4 Receiving objects:  83% (948/1141), 1.46 MiB | 25.00 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery-ui#>=1.9 Receiving objects:  69% (483/700), 652.00 KiB | 57.00 KiB/s
bower progress      font-awesome#~4.4 Receiving objects:  83% (954/1141), 1.48 MiB | 18.00 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery-ui#>=1.9 Receiving objects:  70% (490/700), 684.00 KiB | 58.00 KiB/s
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/totten/angular-jquery-dialog-service.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.123]: errno=Connection timed out

Additional error details: 
fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=Connection timed out
```

I ran `civibuild install` several times several times but it always halt on that particular that step.

Comment: Are you connected to internet while doing this, it might just be an internet error

Comment: @SiddharthGupta Yes. I'm. Several other components are installed successfully from github.com but this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `port 22` was blocked in my connection. That's why it was not able to connect to `git://github.com/totten/angular-jquery-dialog-service.git`.

Comment: So I normally have to switch GIT to use HTTPS rather than the GIT protocol to use civibuild. The instructions to do this can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669091/bower-install-using-only-https

Answer (score 1):

From this line,

> bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/totten/angular-jquery-dialog-service.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.123]: errno=Connection timed out

Check that you have installed git? if not use " sudo apt-get install git" before running the civibuild install command since the command has to fetch from the repository on github.

Also the line

> fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=Connection timed out

shows that there is a problem with the connection you can first run " ping google.com" to test for the connection and then run the civibuild command again.

Comment: "Connection timed out" confirms that `git` is installed, as does Dilip's statement that other modules install correctly before this.